# How is arithmetic overflow avoided by using the Dawson function over the erfi function?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, soft-question

I came across the term *arithmetic overflow* while reading up on the *IEEE754* yesterday, and read up its definition and related terms as well. Today, while reading about the error function and its cousin functions, I came across this statement:

'...where D(x) is the *Dawson function* (which can be used instead of *erfi* to avoid arithmetic overflow).'

Even after having looked up on the relation between the Dawson function and the *erfi* function...  I don't exactly  see how the Dawson function can be used instead of the *erfi* function to avoid *arithmetic overflow*. **Could anyone explain how?**

Edit: I came across this link in wikipedia (near the statement itself as an annotation), but I can't exactly see how this article helps in explaining that...

http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st771-newton/papers/p22-cody.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
{\rm erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{x^2} D(x), \qquad D(x)= e^{-x^2} \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} \, dt,
$$
${\rm erfi}(x)$ will be very much larger in magnitude than $D(x)$ for $x$ of large magnitude (in fact, $D(x)\sim 1/(2x)$ as $|x|\to\infty$, ${\rm erfi}(x)\sim e^{x^2}/(\sqrt{\pi} x)$ as $|x|\to\infty$.)  So, for many large $x$, the value of $D(x)$ will be approximately representable as a floating-point number, while ${\rm erfi}(x)$ would overflow as its magnitude is too large for it to be representable.  For example, $D(30)$ is approximately $0.0167$, while ${\rm erfi(30)}$ exceeds $10^{389}$ and so is not representable as a finite IEEE 754 double-precision floating-point value.